# Past simple or past perfect here?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

I am not sure whether I should use past simple or past perfect here:

> I could've met her when she was in the city, but unfortunately we
>   didn't talk at that time and later when we resumed it turned out she
>   had been here but I **hadn't known / didn't know** about that.

Answer (score 1):

It's "I hadn't known", because the speaker's ignorance was contemporaneous with the fact that she had been there.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence isn't perfectly clear. We don't know if you're describing two missed opportunities, or a situational irony.

SITUATIONAL IRONY

... later, when we resumed, it turned out that she had been here *all along*

With a temporal phrase like **all along** or **for quite a while**, you can eliminate the ambiguity of the past perfect, which might be understood to mean "had been here again briefly for a visit and had left again":

TWO MISSED OPPORTUNITIES

... later, when we resumed, it turned out that she had been here (that is, had been here once again for a  visit)